# tell rake to keep schema_info during rake db:migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openstreetmap, rails-migrations

My database is imported from open street map using a tool Osmosis. Every time I import new data using Osmosis it checks in the table "schema_info" and throws error if "schema_info" is not found.

Now on this same DB I made small modifications using rails migration. After I run rake db:migrate, rake automatically drops the "schema_info" table and replace it with "schema_migration".

Is it possible to tell rake to keep "schema_info" after migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the table in a [migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), as you would for any table. Any modification to the database schema should come in the form of a migration, regardless of how minor.